# how to run runstats command from a java program

Tags: java, sql, spring, db2

I have the following runstats command:

```
RUNSTATS ON TABLE MYSCHEMA.TEST_PRODUCT  ON ALL COLUMNS WITH DISTRIBUTION ON ALL COLUMNS AND DETAILED INDEXES ALL ALLOW WRITE ACCESS
```

I want to run it from inside a java program which is part of a spring project.

How to do it ?

The db2 passwords for connecting to database are encrypted.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: At downvoters: Atleast have the courtesy to put comment as to why the question was downvoted so that I can keep it in mind before future postings!!

Comment: The question is to unspecific to get an real answer, no one knows where to start to describe (explaining Java, explaining Spring, explaining JDBC) - you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the problem is not clear, I only want to point you to this excample

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/samples/jdbc/s-TbRunstats-java.htm

It is an example you find in the IBM DB Reference using Runstats.

Answer (score 5):

RUNSTAT is not SQL. Use SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD.

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD( 'RUNSTATS ON TABLE myschema.mytable ON ALL COLUMNS ALLOW WRITE ACCESS' )
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to use the `ADMIN_CMD` stored procedure:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023587.html

The method used in the @Ralph's answer is really a bad way to do it – but was the only way before IBM added the ADMIN_CMD procedure when DB2 9.1 was released in 2006.